# How to read the data returned by Theo from Neo4j when executing a transaction in Swift?

Tags: swift, database, neo4j, cypher

I have an iOS app in Swift integrated with a Neo4j database using Theo. I want to read the data from the database, so I'm executing a transaction like this:

```
let createStatement = "MATCH (n:`\(labelName)`) RETURN n"       
let resultDataContents = ["row", "graph"]
let statement = ["statement" : createStatement, "resultDataContents" : 
resultDataContents] as [String : Any]
let statements = [statement]

theo.executeTransaction(statements, completionBlock: {(response, error) in
    print("response: \(response)")
})
```

This is executed correctly, and the "response" value is returned with the data, but I don't know how to extract the relationships and properties that I need from it. This is how the data is formatted whenever I print the "response" value:

```
["results": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x60400000f630>(
{
    columns =     (
        n
    );
    data =     (
            {
        graph =             {
            nodes =                 (
                                    {
                    id = 0;
                    labels =                         (
                        "Carl"
                    );
                    properties =                         {
                        image = "gs://nocan-4a3d8.appspot.com/DGHSA4057-D30B-4FC2-995A-E9GASD12FCFA/-LASDFASSIGiZ7cLQhRKaK5";
                    };
                }
            );
            relationships =                 (
            );
        };
        meta =             (
                            {
                deleted = 0;
                id = 0;
                type = node;
            }
        );
        row =             (
                            {
                image = "gs://nocan-4a3d8.appspot.com/61DA4057-FSA0B-4FC2-995A-E9AF3TAFS2FCFA/-LDOIXIGiZ7cLQASDKaK5";
            }
        );
    },
            {
        graph =             {
            nodes =                 (
                                    {
                    id = 1;
                    labels =                         (
                        "Carl"
                    );
                    properties =                         {
                        note = Lgaksdlglksankgas;
                    };
                }
            );
            relationships =                 (
            );
        };
        meta =             (
                            {
                deleted = 0;
                id = 1;
                type = node;
            }
        );
        row =             (
                            {
                note = Lgaksdlglksankgas;
            }
        );
    },
            {
        graph =             {
            nodes =                 (
                                    {
                    id = 20;
                    labels =                         (
                        "Carl"
                    );
                    properties =                         {
                        note = Lkwenglkagsd;
                    };
                }
            );
            relationships =                 (
            );
        };
        meta =             (
                            {
                deleted = 0;
                id = 20;
                type = node;
            }
        );
        row =             (
                            {
                note = Lkwenglkagsd;
            }
        );
    },
            {
        graph =             {
            nodes =                 (
                                    {
                    id = 40;
                    labels =                         (
                        "Carl"
                    );
                    properties =                         {
                        image = "gs://nocan-4a3d8.appspot.com/5MAFSA4057-D30B-4FC2-995A-2DAKASD412FCFA/-LEOIXQ8MZ4lvOWvlka7";
                    };
                }
            );
            relationships =                 (
            );
        };
        meta =             (
                            {
                deleted = 0;
                id = 40;
                type = node;
            }
        );
        row =             (
                            {
                image = "gs://nocan-4a3d8.appspot.com/DGA7A4057-830B-4FC2-995A-E9ADI3DA2FCFA/-WEFDOIX5SMZ4lvOWvlka7";
            }
        );
      }
  );
}
)
, "errors": <__NSArray0 0x600000005db0>(

)
]
```

What kind of object even is this? How do I extract the data and the values that I need? I am just lost. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `response` is a dictionary (`[String:Any]`). You pull out what you need just like any Swift dictionary.

Comment: You are facing the "you get what you asked for"-problem. You asked for a resultset containing nodes (n) and that is exactly what you are getting. Note that Cypher can return lots of different things and thus the resultset has to be able to handle all of those. Try with some tabular results (***RETURN n.image AS imageurl***  for example) first to get a feel for it.